# How do I pass a list of tuples as an argument in a function?

Tags: list, function, tuples, sml

I want to write a function that takes as an argument a list of three tuples.

What I have isn't passing the eval, as I assume that it's reading it as tuple of two ints plus an int list:

`fun check_list(tuples : int*int*int list) = so forth and so forth`

What is the proper syntax for typing a list of tuples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your syntax.

This `int*int*int list` is equivalent to `int * int * (int list)`

But what you meant is `(int * int * int) list`. The use of parentheses should make it clearer.

Answer (score -1):

if you want a tuple of three ints then you would pass to a function like so:

```
fun check_list(a:int,b:int,c:int)=[(a,b,c)];

check_list(1,2,3);
```

plug it in and try it. I will return [(1,2,3)].  If I'm understanding your question correctly.

Comment: The question might not have been the clearest of questions, but it is plainly obvious that you are not answering the question that was asked. See @EdwinDalorzo's correct answer.